SSHD ListenAddress to only listen at 10.0.0.0/8 and 172.16.0.0/12 and 192.168.0.0/16
$ grep ListenAddress /etc/ssh/sshd_config
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
$

this would only listen on IPv4.
But Question: how can it listen ONLY on 10.0.0.0/8 and 172.16.0.0/12 and 192.168.0.0/16 ?

Do you have address on the machine from these networks?

You can't "listen" on a range of addresses; you can only bind to specific addresses (so e.g. you can listen on 10.0.0.10, but you can't listen on 10.0.0.0/8). You can use netfilter rules (iptables, nftables) to implement address-range based restrictions.

ListenAddress is not about addresses of clients that the ssh server will accept connections from, it's about which of the addresses of the server machine sshd will answer at, or in other words which addresses it will be reachable by (of course ignoring NAT).
For instance, if your server has 3 network interfaces with these given IPv4 interfaces:



interface
IP address
netmask




lo
127.0.0.1
255.0.0.0


eth0
10.0.1.2
255.0.0.0


eth1
192.168.1.1
255.255.255.0



With ListenAddress 0.0.0.0 (the default), 0.0.0.0 being the INADDR_ANY IPv4 address, it will accept any connection through any of its interfaces to any of those local addresses.
With ListenAddress 127.0.0.1, only connections to 127.0.0.1 on the loopback interface will be accepted.
With ListenAddress 10.0.1.2, only connections to that address will be accepted, but from any client, regardless of their own IP address.
To filter based on the client source IP addresses, you can use:

sshd's AllowUsers *@10.0.0.0/8 *@172.16.0.0/12 *@192.168.0.0/16
sshd's Match Host, Match Address for more fine grained rules
if built with tcp wrapper support, control it via /etc/hosts.{allow,deny}
if PAM support is enabled, you may be able to do it at PAM level via the pam_access module and /etc/security/access.conf

Though the safest would be to do it at the host firewall level so connections don't reach sshd at all.
